# How can I perform Hot Code Replace in Tomcat web application running outside eclipse?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I am using Hot Code Replace feature when Tomcat is running from eclipse and it works great.

But, how can I do this manually when Tomcat is running outside eclipse?

After some searching, I have found that I need to use an agent like HotswapAgent. But, they are using this agent with modified JDK called DCEVM. I don't want to use modified JDK. I want to achieve the same thing with OpenJDK.

I know that modification will be limited to method body only but, that's not a problem for me. How can I achieve the exact same thing eclipse is doing for Hot Code Replace for an externally running Tomcat without using IDE?

Edit : Eclipse example is just to clarify what I want to achieve. I do not want to use eclipse at all. I just want to do Hot Code Replace in an application running in Tomcat.

Comment: Why not just redeploy a new war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to perform Hot Code Replace in a running JVM. This involves several steps.

1. Prepare (compile) the new version of classes you want to replace. Let's say, you want to replace `org.pkg.MyClass`, and the new version of this class is located at `/new/path/org/pkg/MyClass.class`
2. Create a Java Agent that uses [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to [redefine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses(java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...)) the given class. Here is how the simplest agent may look like:

   ```
   import java.lang.instrument.*;
   import java.nio.file.*;

   public class HotCodeReplace {

       public static void agentmain(String args, Instrumentation instr) throws Exception {
           Class oldClass = Class.forName("org.pkg.MyClass");

           Path newFile = Paths.get("/new/path/org/pkg/MyClass.class");
           byte[] newData = Files.readAllBytes(newFile);

           instr.redefineClasses(new ClassDefinition(oldClass, newData));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Compile the above agent and pack it into `.jar` with the following `MANIFEST.MF`

   ```
   Agent-Class: HotCodeReplace
   Can-Redefine-Classes: true
   ```

   The command to create `HotCodeReplace.jar`:

   ```
   jar cvfm HotCodeReplace.jar MANIFEST.MF HotCodeReplace.class
   ```
4. Load the agent .jar into the target JVM. This can be done with [Attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) or simply with [`jattach`](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) utility:

   ```
   jattach <pid> load instrument false /path/to/HotCodeReplace.jar
   ```

[More about Java agents »](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlcF8awgUEE)